# Grouping data into buckets by frequency in Postgres 11.6

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, grouping, histogram, window-functions

Using Postgres 11.6, I'm trying to analyze some event data. The goal is to find the durations for all events with a specific name, and then split *each* one out into evenly sized buckets. We're looking for any times that "clump" for a specific event. I'm editing my question as the specific case may be obscuring what I'm trying to ask.

## Simple example

The question is "how do you group rows by a value, then split occurrences by frequency into buckets with count and average for each of those buckets." Here's a hand-done toy example with rounded averages:

Months with values, each number here represents a row.

```
Jan    12    24    60    150    320    488                        
Feb     8    16    40    100    220                            
Mar     4     8    20    310
```

Overall figures

```
Month    Count    Avg    Min    Max                                
Jan      6        176    12    488                                
Feb      5         77     8    220                                
Mar      4         86     4    310
```

The same original data, but with more data, including repeated values and a wider range.

```
Jan    12    12    12    12    24    24    60     60    150    320     488    500
Feb     8     8     8     8     8    16    40    100    220    440    1100    
Mar     4     8     8     8     8    20    20     20     20    310
```

Overall figures

```
Month    Count    Avg    Min     Max                                
Jan      12       140    12      500                                
Feb      11       178     8     1100                                
Mar      10        43     4      310
```

Mock-up of one of the sets of data split out into 3 buckets

```
Month    Count    Avg    Min    Max    Bucket                            
Jan      4         12     12     12    0                            
Jan      4         42     24     60    1                            
Jan      4        365    150    500    2                            
...and so on for Feb and Mar
```

I'm just guessing at how the buckets would split in the mock-up above.

That pretty much captures what I'm trying to do. Group by month name (from_to_node in my real case), split the resulting rows into buckets, and then get min, max, avg, and count *for each bucket*. It's starting to sound like a pivot (?)

## Real Table Setup

Here's the structure of table I'm getting a feed for:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.edge_event (
    id uuid,
    inv_id uuid,
    facility_id uuid,
    from_node citext,
    to_node citext,
    from_to_node citext,
    from_node_dts timestamp without time zone,
    to_node_dts timestamp without time zone,
    seconds integer,
    cycle_id uuid
);
```

The duration is pre-calculated in seconds, and the area of interest for now is only the from_to_node name. So, it's fair to think of the example as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.edge_event (
    from_to_node citext,
    seconds integer
);
```

## Raw Data

Within the `edge_event` table, there are 159 distinct `from_to_node` values over around 300K event rows. Some are found in only a handful of `edge_event` records, some are found in thousands, or tens of thousands. That's too much to provide a good sample for. But to make the problem simpler to follow, a `from_to_node` might be

`Boxing_Assembly 1256`

Meaning "it took 1256 seconds to move this part from the Boxing phase to the Assembly phase." And here we might have 10,000 other records for "Boxing_Assembly" with different durations.

## Goal

We're looking for two things out of each `from_to_node`. For something like Boxing_Assembly, I'm trying to do this:

1. Sort the seconds taken into buckets, say 20 buckets. This is for a histogram.
2. For each bucket get the
   count of edge_event rows
   avg(seconds) within the bucket
   min/first_value(seconds) within the bucket
   max/last_value(seconds) within the bucket

So, we're looking to chart durations to look for clusters, and then get the raw seconds out of any common clusters.

## What I've tried

I've tried a lot of different code, and I've not succeeded. It seems like a problem for `GROUP BY` and/or window functions. There's something I'm not getting, as my results are far from the mark.

I know that I haven't provided sample data, which makes it harder to help. But I'm guessing that what I'm missing is one++ concepts. Pretty much, I want to know how to split out the `edge_event` data by from_to_node and then by seconds. Given the huge ranges across from_to_nodes, I'm trying to bucket each individually based on their own min/max.

Thanks very much for any help.

## Draft Attempt

I've developed a query that works a bit, but not entirely. This is an edit from my original post with broken code.

```
WITH
min_max AS
(
    SELECT from_to_node,
           min(seconds),
           max(seconds)

     FROM edge_event

 GROUP BY from_to_node
) 

   SELECT edge_event.from_to_node,
           width_bucket (seconds, min_max.min, min_max.max, 99) as bucket, -- Bucket are counted from 0, so 9 gets you 10 buckets, if you have enough data.
          count(*) as frequency,
          min(seconds) as seconds_min,
          max(seconds) as seconds_max,
          max(seconds) - min(seconds) as bucket_width,
          round(avg(seconds)) as seconds_avg

      FROM edge_event
      JOIN min_max ON (min_max.from_to_node = edge_event.from_to_node)

     WHERE min_max.min <> min_max.max AND -- Can't have a bucket with an upper and lower bound that are the same.
             edge_event.from_to_node IN (
                'Boxing_Assembly',
                'Assembly_Waiting For QA')

  GROUP BY edge_event.from_to_node,
             bucket

  ORDER BY from_to_node,
           bucket
```

What I'm getting back looks pretty good:

```
from_to_node            bucket   frequency    seconds_min   seconds_max     bucket_width   seconds_avg
Boxing_Assembly              1         912            17           7052     7035                  3037
Boxing_Assembly              2         226          7058          13937     6879                  9472
Boxing_Assembly              3          41         14151          21058     6907                 16994
Boxing_Assembly              4          16         21149          27657     6508                 23487
Boxing_Assembly              5           4         28926          33896     4970                 30867
Boxing_Assembly              6           1         37094          37094        0                 37094
Boxing_Assembly              7           1         43228          43228        0                 43228
Boxing_Assembly             10           2         63666          64431      765                 64049
Boxing_Assembly             14           1         94881          94881        0                 94881
Boxing_Assembly             16           1         108254        108254        0                108254
Boxing_Assembly             37           1         257226        257226        0                257226
Boxing_Assembly             40           1         275140        275140        0                275140
Boxing_Assembly             68           1         471727        471727        0                471727
Boxing_Assembly            100           1         696732        696732        0                696732
Assembly_Waiting For QA      1       41875              1         18971    18970                   726
Assembly_Waiting For QA      9           1         207457        207457        0                207457
Assembly_Waiting For QA     15           1         336711        336711        0                336711
Assembly_Waiting For QA     38           1         906519        906519        0                906519
Assembly_Waiting For QA    100           1        2369669       2369669        0               2369669
```

One problem here is that the buckets aren't evenly sized...they seem kind of weird. I've also tried specifying 10, 20, or 100 buckets, and get similar results. I'm hoping that there is a better way to allocate the data to buckets that I'm missing, and that there's a way to have zero-entry buckets instead of gaps.

Comment: You might want to look into the Postgres [width_bucket](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-math.html) functions. Also posting sample data - as text not an image - and the expected results from that data would greatly enhnce you getting a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just this minute added a mocked example with data (as text) to better get the idea across. And, yes, I suspect `width_bucket` is what I want....I tried it in the failed example I posted earlier.

Comment: I've updated my question with a draft that works better than my original broken example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PostgreSQL optimizer for that. It collects exactly the information you want.

Create a temporary table with the values you are interested in and `ANALYZE` it. Then look into `pg_stats` for the following:

- if there are "most common values", you have them and their frequency right there.
- Otherwise, look for adjacent histogram boundaries that are close together. Such a bucket is an interval where values are "lumped".

Comment: Hey, that's a cool idea, I'll try that. Would you suggest tweaking `ALTER TABLE SET STATISTICS` for this sort of thing?

Comment: Sure, if you need more than 100 buckets.

Comment: This idea with `pg_stats` seems very clever, and quite promising. Is the basic idea to 1) select the data, 2) push it into a temporary table, 3) `ANALYZE`, 4) `unnest` the histogram boundaries, 5) `LEFT JOIN` against those boundaries to bucket the source data? That seems like it should work pretty well, but it's also not an obvious solution, and is completely Postgres-specific. Is there another way to generate histogram bounds from a series in Postgres?

Comment: Of course you can reimplement how PostgreSQL gathers statistics, Vittel's algorithm and all. You got the idea, but the query will be slightly more complicated, because you have to calculate the difference between adjacent histogram bounds. I think that all databases worth the salt will have a histogram in their statistics, but of course the implementation will vary wildly.